# Как открыть из своего Android приложения приложение Google Maps с заданными координатами?

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps, android-intent, геолокация

Но не используя Intent `geo`, а используя именно какой-то гугловский Intent.

Для примера, у Яндекса всё просто и понятно `yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?pt=" + lat + "," + lon + "&z=12&l=map` - открывается приложение Яндекс.Карты с заданными координатами и меткой в указанной точке.

Как сделать то же самое с Google Maps? Перерыл весь интернет, нашел только google.streetwview. В остальном всё только о `geo`.

**Почему не подходит `geo`?** Потому что `geo` общий Intent для всех подобных приложений, и при его вызове появляется окно с выбором чем же конкретно открыть эти координаты. Но мне нужно открывать без окна выбора, заранее предопределенным приложением, потому что в настройках моего приложения пользователь уже сделал выбор каким именно приложением открывать карты.

И вопрос в догонку: как вообще определять/где смотреть какие Intent'ы используются приложением и что они вызывают?

Comment: а почему бы в `intent` не засунуть `package` Google Maps - `intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"))
startActivity(intent)
```

Java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

В итоге, если есть приложение гугл карт они откроются, если нет - откроется сайт

Ну и гугловский гайд [первый](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) и [второй](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)

Answer (score 0):

Можно в качестве адреса использовать просто ссылку:

```
 public void showMap(View view) {
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.ru/maps/place/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82/@50.6153435,38.6872866,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x41247607cb97236d:0x59255fe78cc52fc7!8m2!3d50.6153435!4d38.6894753");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```